# Decode a proprietary H264 network video stream

Tags: java, ffmpeg, video-streaming, h.264, javacv

I have incoming byte streams probably encoded in H264 from a RTSP camera through a websocket in my spring boot application,

I need to decode the incoming H264 streams to transmit the video to my frontend clients.
I have tried using javaCV/FFMpeg but nothing works.

**Any help would be appreciated**

this is the part of hex dump received through socket

```
00000000: 01 00 00 00 04 48 32 36 34 00 00 00 24 38 65 34    .....H264...$8e4
00000010: 32 39 65 37 61 2D 32 66 34 66 2D 34 37 31 61 2D    29e7a-2f4f-471a-
00000020: 39 61 63 30 2D 66 66 62 38 64 64 37 63 37 64 37    9ac0-ffb8dd7c7d7
00000030: 32 00 00 00 D4 7B 22 49 73 49 6E 69 74 22 3A 66    2...T{"IsInit":f
00000040: 61 6C 73 65 2C 22 49 73 41 75 64 69 6F 22 3A 66    alse,"IsAudio":f
00000050: 61 6C 73 65 2C 22 54 6F 74 61 6C 53 65 63 6F 6E    alse,"TotalSecon
00000060: 64 73 22 3A 30 2E 30 36 2C 22 46 72 61 6D 65 54    ds":0.06,"FrameT
00000070: 69 6D 65 22 3A 22 32 30 32 33 2D 30 32 2D 32 33    ime":"2023-02-23
00000080: 54 30 34 3A 32 31 3A 35 33 2E 35 33 31 5A 22 2C    T04:21:53.531Z",
00000090: 22 53 65 71 75 65 6E 63 65 49 64 22 3A 31 2C 22    "SequenceId":1,"
000000a0: 42 61 73 65 44 65 63 6F 64 65 54 69 6D 65 22 3A    BaseDecodeTime":
000000b0: 32 36 35 38 37 2C 22 4D 65 64 69 61 54 69 6D 65    26587,"MediaTime
000000c0: 22 3A 32 36 35 38 37 2C 22 49 73 46 72 61 6D 65    ":26587,"IsFrame
000000d0: 48 69 64 64 65 6E 22 3A 66 61 6C 73 65 2C 22 49    Hidden":false,"I
000000e0: 73 4B 65 79 46 72 61 6D 65 22 3A 66 61 6C 73 65    sKeyFrame":false
000000f0: 2C 22 49 64 22 3A 34 34 35 2C 22 47 65 6E 65 72    ,"Id":445,"Gener
00000100: 61 74 69 6F 6E 22 3A 31 7D 00 00 3F 50 00 00 00    ation":1}..?P...
00000110: 68 6D 6F 6F 66 00 00 00 10 6D 66 68 64 00 00 00    hmoof....mfhd...
00000120: 00 00 00 01 BD 00 00 00 50 74 72 61 66 00 00 00    ....=...Ptraf...
00000130: 10 74 66 68 64 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00    .tfhd...........
00000140: 14 74 66 64 74 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 67    .tfdt..........g
00000150: DB 00 00 00 24 74 72 75 6E 01 00 0F 01 00 00 00    [...$trun.......
00000160: 01 00 00 00 70 00 00 00 3C 00 00 3E E0 00 01 00    ....p...<..>`...
00000170: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3E E8 6D 64 61 74 00 00 3E    .......>hmdat..>
00000180: DC 41 E1 81 80 93 BE 16 2B 33 77 3D 4C B6 55 8B    \Aa...>.+3w=L6U.
00000190: D2 55 60 92 05 F7 F7 A4 97 54 4B 6C A6 68 48 84    RU`..ww$.TKl&hH.
000001a0: 68 FF D2 B6 6C 02 31 FC 24 01 78 EA BD 20 AD 15    h.R6l.1|$.xj=.-.
000001b0: F1 73 31 4B EB EF 18 1B 50 B3 13 F2 DC C6 4C E1    qs1Kko..P3.r\FLa
000001c0: 75 8B 94 52 6B C5 09 37 55 1E 45 66 6A 92 39 23    u..RkE.7U.Efj.9#
000001d0: C9 2D FD BB EC AD FD CF C4 30 75 FF 44 66 FA 85    I-};l-}OD0u.Dfz.
000001e0: D9 7C 18 72 AE 63 45 60 DD D7 65 44 84 49 95 8D    Y|.r.cE`]WeD.I..
000001f0: 2C 70 6C 57 8E E9 A9 EB B6 F6 78 BD D6 88 99 F6    ,plW.i)k6vx=V..v
00000200: FC 25 B1 0A FF DF CB 77 6A 67 37 24 A5 3D 8F A1    |%1.._Kwjg7$%=.!
00000210: 27 9B 4F 42 0E CD B8 87 6E C9 99 FC 6F 4C 53 4B    '.OB.M8.nI.|oLSK
00000220: 01 EA B6 AF 99 F8 22 C1 8F 1E C1 66 D6 8A 09 D6    .j6/.x"A..AfV..V
00000230: 99 79 91 F7 C1 2A 08 1F 81 CB 5E DD C3 CA 86 8F    .y.wA*...K^]CJ..
00000240: 57 BF 17 A2 64 6B 69 56 AE 19 1F 57 AD A6 D8 C2    W?."dkiV...W-&XB
00000250: 06 28 EB 46 D3 E4 85 51 3E E2 A5 40 50 50 85 7D    .(kFSd.Q>b%@PP.}
00000260: 72 6B 20 87 1A 6E 73 E1 B8 88 9E 20 23 48 6D FE    rk...nsa8...#Hm~
00000270: C2 0D 39 ED 24 B2 6D B5 9B 81 B6 BC F4 EE DE A2    B.9m$2m5..6<tn^"
00000280: CF A1 08 D0 D2 5B EE FA 0D DA FD 3B 79 C7 89 E5    O!.PR[nz.Z};yG.e
00000290: 4F 64 73 37 98 D6 2D 47 1D 8B A3 47 DD EA C9 8E    Ods7.V-G..#G]jI.
000002a0: 3E 8C 97 E2 42 15 FB 22 A6 83 A1 34 18 52 5E 35    >..bB.{"&.!4.R^5
000002b0: 2A A6 E2 71 D7 4F 96 0A EC AE 8D 39 27 B8 CF 61    *&bqWO..l..9'8Oa
000002c0: CC ED E9 AF 74 C3 95 D3 E3 96 32 20 E6 31 0B E4    Lmi/tC.Sc.2.f1.d
000002d0: DC F4 FF 41 37 36 E7 DB 87 AE B3 7D BF CA F8 05    \t.A76g[..3}?Jx.
000002e0: 72 2A 38 AB B8 8E 98 43 97 C8 5E 80 57 C6 E7 1E    r*8+8..C.H^.WFg.
000002f0: 86 75 CE CD CE BF CF 10 C9 8A C2 C9 6E 33 41 AC    .uNMN?O.I.BIn3A,
00000300: 91 AC A8 F3 1B E6 D5 0A 22 A1 2C 4C 68 19 51 4D    .,(s.fU."!,Lh.QM
00000310: 17 DA AE E1 D7 BC 0E 2D F8 14 61 E2 4F BA 26 A3    .Z.aW<.-x.abO:&#
00000320: 0A E4 A6 BE 08 EA 3C 28 E6 C5 6B CA 3A 86 D2 59    .d&>.j<(fEkJ:.RY
00000330: 34 C2 ED 91 72 5A EF 2C BE D7 38 A4 60 D7 F3 97    4Bm.rZo,>W8$`Ws.
00000340: BB E6 FD C2 D0 29 10 B5 A4 79 D8 3E 61 48 8A F9    ;f}BP).5$yX>aH.y
00000350: C6 D8 13 D0 FD DB D6 FA 24 7F CD 5A BF 06 57 49    FX.P}[Vz$.MZ?.WI
00000360: 51 EC ED B2 74 AB 92 1D 37 68 70 A2 A5 31 B5 5F    Qlm2t+..7hp"%15_
00000370: EA CF 9E 3E 6A B1 78 16 B7 94 D1 46 7B 63 C1 67    jO.>j1x.7.QF{cAg
00000380: D2 B0 08 44 64 1E 68 15 39 80 E3 DD EB C0 E1 71    R0.Dd.h.9.c]k@aq
00000390: E8 EE D0 4D DF 4F 41 E0 96 C5 34 AD BC D3 9E 88    hnPM_OA`.E4-<S..
000003a0: 0B 17 D8 7D 3A A8 3B 06 78 79 93 B7 30 92 C8 D8    ..X}:(;.xy.70.HX
000003b0: 5D 27 04 D7 00 9F E3 EA A3 C6 BD B9 05 21 5C 68    ]'.W..cj#F=9.!\h
000003c0: 45 DB 90 2A 05 38 79 D9 84 60 C7 F2 BB DE 1B 5A    E[.*.8yY.`Gr;^.Z
000003d0: 44 0B ED 67 34 DF 07 8B F5 04 27 9E 1A F0 04 CA    D.mg4_..u.'..p.J
000003e0: 86 B1 2C 0B 78 D0 58 86 81 62 D8 70 3D BA 9D 51    .1,.xPX..bXp=:.Q
000003f0: D8 2C 6C 6A 10 88 B9 F8 89 3D 6F 39 C2 52 49 CF    X,lj..9x.=o9BRIO
00000400: 9F C1 50 6A D4 9E A5 96 B2 0A 99 1D 6B BC 63 03    .APjT.%.2...k<c.
00000410: A4 8C 7E 1D BD DF 8B D8 97 EE 9A 59 78 63 FC 74    $.~.=_.X.n.Yxc|t
00000420: 3B 40 75 AF A7 1A B7 F0 56 A5 5F 3E 81 54 83 A0    ;@u/'.7pV%_>.T..
00000430: 7F FC AD 71 CE AF 54 8B 5D DC 27 34 20 A3 0A 73    .|-qN/T.]\'4.#.s
00000440: 76 A5 81 33 22 31 56 6B 1D 82 C4 32 FB 82 15 F6    v%.3"1Vk..D2{..v
00000450: 97 C8 47 29 3C 9E 59 9A C0 83 48 A0 55 CB C8 D6    .HG)<.Y.@.H.UKHV
00000460: 36 92 CC 54 A7 00 E3 28 9E 99 45 B2 E5 7E 88 A7    6.LT'.c(..E2e~.'
00000470: 28 4E CA 75 17 3C D3 B5 6C F5 FD AC 05 55 BF F7    (NJu.<S5lu},.U?w
00000480: 98 61 92 30 D8 0F 0E A5 DD 61 4D 80 27 5B A7 68    .a.0X..%]aM.'['h
00000490: E5 B9 C2 B8 EE 31 F6 63 29 37 C5 C9 11 39 90 8D    e9B8n1vc)7EI.9..
000004a0: D8 00 35 F4 7A 2D 79 D0 6A BB 9C 98 E4 41 CF 3F    X.5tz-yPj;..dAO?
000004b0: DE 9D 8B BF 04 69 1D BC 5C E7 E1 F2 49 01 8D F5    ^..?.i.<\garI..u
000004c0: 41 3E 3F FB AE 54 B2 D9 F2 A0 E8 0A F7 59 47 77    A>?{.T2Yr.h.wYGw
000004d0: 3C 19 C8 7B 81 9B 17 19 E9 81 A0 36 AD C6 62 71    <.H{....i..6-Fbq
000004e0: DB 68 72 8F 6A 37 45 D9 0E 6E DC 2C 5E 52 C2 75    [hr.j7EY.n\,^RBu
000004f0: 51 2F F9 CE 8A 10 12 E9 C8 68 A9 D6 A6 D7 5B 14    Q/yN...iHh)V&W[.
00000500: 11 51 42 FD BE B5 09 56 7F 19 C3 EB A7 A6 DF 6C    .QB}>5.V..Ck'&_l
00000510: 55 A3 11 DC EF 81 C3 CD DD 63 BF 38 F8 5A 4A 45    U#.\o.CM]c?8xZJE
00000520: 33 24 7B A4 55 B3 85 A6 87 75 3B 85 51 5C 03 B7    3${$U3.&.u;.Q\.7
```

**UPDATE TO THE CODE**

1st Packet [find here](https://pastebin.com/embed_js/3Ca8ZDFk)
2nd Packet [find here](https://pastebin.com/embed_js/FEuwQay6)

I have updated the code as per one of the comment to read only MDAT box to retrieve H264 stream from the incoming bytes[] through the socket, now I send only MDAT box contents (next byte after MDAT box)

```
public Map.Entry<Boolean, List<Integer>> hasMdat(byte[] byteArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.length - 3; i++) {
        if (byteArray[i] == (byte) 109 &&
                byteArray[i + 1] == (byte) 100 &&
                byteArray[i + 2] == (byte) 97 &&
                byteArray[i + 3] == (byte) 116) {

            return Map.entry(true, Arrays.asList(i, i + 1, i + 2, i + 3));
        }
    }
    return Map.entry(false, List.of(0));
}
```

This is my code which handles the byte stream

```
initSocketConnection(new VideoStreamCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onVideoStreamReceived(byte[] bytes) {
           
Map.Entry<Boolean, List<Integer>> b = hasMdat(bytes);
        if (b.getKey()) {
            byte[] b1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, b.getValue().get(3) + 1, bytes.length);
  //write b1 back to client using spring SSE
            
        }

        }
    });
```

Comment: This appears to be fragmented MP4 rather than a raw H264 bitstream with some proprietary data at front. The fragment starts at `0x10d` (4th byte before `moof`). The video payload starts at `0x17d` but if you ignore the container, you will lose timing info.

Comment: could you please explain more.. regarding the decode part (this is a live stream)

Comment: It has syntax elements of an MP4 like moof, mdat..etc. To decode the container, you will need a MP4 demuxer. To decode just the H264, locate `mdat` in each packet and start decode from next byte.

Comment: hi @gyan can u suggest some java based libraries to demux/decode the bitstream. an example code would be great

Comment: Not familiar with Java packages.

Comment: hexdump looks like it contains length-prefixed strings/blobs. initial 01h, no clue why, but then follow frames: [00 00 00 04h]"H264" and [00 00 00 24h]"<some guid>" and [D4h]"<some json>" and [3F 50h]"<mp4/mov file>" -- try dumping that. it's probably a MOV or MP4 file (mp4 is a subset of mov).

Comment: I need to transmit these byte stream to any playable format and then transmit to my frontend, any possible solutions pls.

Comment: the GUID, in the dump is signalR socked connection ID thru which the byte stream is received. please guide me through some possible ways to decode the mov/mp4 to any playable format

Comment: @al_mukthar **(1)** You need to show a full hex sequence of bytes for a packet like: `01 00 00 00 04 48 32 36 34 ...etc` otherwise your currently shown hex dump (with the offsets and the UTF texts included) is un-usable to us for testing. **(2)** Show a hex sequence for the first received packet, it should have the main metadata. **(3)** Show a hex sequence for the 2nd received packet, it should have a keyframe's data (needed to display other pictures). **(4)** You only need `start += 4;` at the code ending, the second While loop is not needed. **(5)** How do you play MP4 files in Java?

Comment: @VC.One I have updated the question to include the 1 and 2 received packet hex. also I have modified the code to read only MDAT as per Gyans comment above to get only H264 stream. answering your 5th question, I don't want to play the video in Java. I need to transmit the stream(H264) or somehow to my frontend to play

Comment: then DON'T do any of that, and simply take that entire MP4 file and serve it

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz that doesnt seems working, i served the bytes[] array received as is to the frontend through a websocket and tried playing the stream, it doesnt work.. any possible ways to decode just video frames. Im ok with losing the audio

Comment: can't see what you did, can't debug it. this should not be construed as an offer to debug java code or anything running in a browser. just review [mre] and remember that "it doesn't work" is never debuggable.

Comment: @al_mukthar **(1)** Although you have an accepted Answer, I suspect you do not need to actually extract the H.264 out of MP4 (but your wording makes it seem like that's what you need to do). You might be creating harder work than needed for displaying frames. **(2)** Try connecting to the camera before it transmits so that the first frame is maybe a keyframe, if you connect later than camera's first transmitted packet then you might miss the keyframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"I have incoming byte streams **probably encoded in H264** from a Genetec
> camera..."*
>  *"I need to decode the **incoming H264 streams** to transmit the video to my frontend..."*

**Note**: If your *"frontend"* playback system can play MP4 then you already have a playable file as given. There is no need to extract H.264 bytes from within MP4 bytes, or convert bytes to AnnexB format, or adding Start-codes, or skipping audio frames, etc. Simply remove the starting Genetec header and the rest of data is a playable MP4.

This answer below is for when the playback system accepts chunked MP4 data (H.264 contained in MP4).
If the player expects actual raw H.264 frames then for extraction: see the Answer by [Markus Schumann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75596149/2057709).

##### ## Shortest version:

From each packet:

- At offset `[49]` read a skippable *"Size"* from the 32-bit integer (is in Big-Endian format).
- MP4 data begins at `int mp4_data_pos = (49 + skipSize);`.
- Extract MP4 data parts only, and use them for testing as video playback.
- In MP4 data: `[moov]` is metadata and then chunks are `[moof+mdat]` ... `[moof+mdat]`.
- Find **moov** as: `0x6D6F6F76`, find **moof** as: `0x6D6F6F66`, find **mdat** as: `0x6D646174`.
- Get a size of each atom by reading a 32-bit integer from the previous four bytes.
   (*eg:* `int size_mdat = read_32_bits_from( pos_mdat - 4);` since one array slot holds 8 bits).
- First `[moof + mdat]` chunk after the metadata part must contain a keyframe for display.
- Find keyframe through checking for a frame type **5** with:
  `int frame_type = ( byteArray[ mdat_pos + 8 ] & 0x1F );`
  (*NB 1:* This will only find a keyframe if it's the first frame in a chunk (*eg:* a `[moof + mdat]` package).
  (*NB 2:* It's possible your Genetec device outputs a keyframe later (*eg:* every 25th frame) or else maybe it only emits a keyframe at device start-up? Check for such an issue if not getting a keyframe.
- If testing with an HTML5 video tag, then your codec setup is: `avc1.640028`.
- If testing as file then save N-amount of "MP4 data" parts as one file (*ie:* file is the joined MP4 chunks).

##### ## Short version:

[ to add later: Image of header sections to skip + with 32-bit integers highlighted ]

In each packet...

- Skip ahead, past the first 49 bytes.
- At offset 49, read a 32-bit integer (*ie:* to update some "skipSize" variable).
- Skip ahead (past some Object bytes) by the new amount from skipSize variable.
- MP4 data begins here (*eg:* `mp4_begins_pos = (49 + skipSize);`.

Some notes about MP4 data in packets:

- MP4 data is up to end of packet, and may have a larger size than the current packet size.
- MP4 data which is larger than the packet's own size will continue in the next packet.
- in bytes: `moov` atom has required MP4 metadata, and `moof` atom is a playable MP4 chunk.
- in bytes: an MP4 atom begins with a SIZE (32-bits or 4 bytes), followed by atom NAME.
- in bytes: Copy all atoms (in order of appearance) by their SIZEs into a new bytes array.
   This array can be saved as a file or sent to a decoder for playback.

**(Option A)** For **online playback** (*using HTML5 video tag*): 
Send the array of "**MP4 data**" parts only to your front-end.
*(meaning all packet bytes **minus the first 49 bytes** and also **minus the Object bytes** (by its **size**))*.

Web playback means choosing either:

- Using [MediaSource Extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API) API to manually feed received chunks to the browser's MPEG decoder.
- Using a server-side script as tag's `src`, where the script "pipes" the MP4 data back into the video tag.
- Pre-saving the chunks on server as they arrive, then using HLS [Live Playlist](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/example_playlists_for_http_live_streaming/live_playlist_sliding_window_construction) format to serve frontend clients.

From the STSD atom I can see you have: H.264 "High" profile @ level 4.0 (or **avc1.640028**).

```
type= video/mp4; codecs= "avc1.640028";
```

**(Option B)** To **save as a file** for quick testing: 
**Concat** (join) your required N-amount of "**MP4 data**" parts into one long array, then save that array as a file. Test the new MP4 file from your storage folder in a player like [VLC Media Player](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.en_GB.html).

##### ## Long version:

The format of Genetec's MP4 header is easy enough to understand:

**(1)** Each packet begins with some **49 bytes** of skippable values.

- **(a)** Each packet's **first byte** value is **0x01**.

  - Confirm with a `if (byteArray[0] == 1) { /* is OK packet */ }`.
  - Else assume there is some packet corruption. Skip/ignore such packets.
- **(b)** Followed by 32-int for size of data, and then data itself: is type **String** (*eg:* `H264`).

  - example packet-1 bytes: `00 00 00 04` (=4) then `48 32 36 34` (=H264)
- **(c)** Followed by 32-int size for possible GUUID (seems to be enough hex values for 16 bytes).

  - example packet-1 bytes: `00 00 00 24` (=36) then `XXXX-XX-XX-etc` style hex values.

This above data seems to be always 49 bytes. Confirm by checking other packets, (is there a pattern of 49 bytes that are: a string of "H264" followed by a sequence of "XXXX-XX-XX-etc" style values?).

- **Skip** past these 49 bytes (of Genetec's custom header bytes).
- Skip range is `[byte 0] ... [byte 48]`, since these bytes are not needed for playback.

**(2)** After skipping, there is an [Object](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_classes.asp) (added by Genetec) of side metadata (*eg*: `{"IsAudio":false}` ).

- **(a)** From **offset 49** onwards, read a 32-bit integer for the **size** (bytes length) of the Object.

  - example packet-1 bytes: `00 00 00 C8` == is **size** of 36 bytes
- **(b)** Skip the Object bytes by using the found size (to land at example position: **offset N**).

  - These custom Object's bytes are not needed for playback.

**(3)** At **offset N**, the actual MP4 data begins.

Here is a starting example code to check the packet for MP4 data size to extract for playback.

Use the **read_int32** function that I've provided to get a 32-bit integer from some Array position.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main 
{
    //# Vars for MP4 data
    public static int size_MP4_data = 0;
    public static int size_expected_MP4_data = 0;
    public static int size_received_MP4_data = 0;
    public static int offset_MP4_data = 0;
    
    public static boolean need_more_MP4_data = false;
     
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //# Example Array to represent a received input Packet
        //# Array contents are from the first 320 bytes of your first example packet
        //# See full bytes at: https://pastebin.com/embed_js/3Ca8ZDFk 
        int[] bytes_Packet =    {

                                    0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x48, 0x32, 0x36, 0x34, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x24, 0x39, 0x33, 0x65, 
                                    0x63, 0x35, 0x39, 0x31, 0x30, 0x2D, 0x65, 0x65, 0x35, 0x38, 0x2D, 0x34, 0x39, 0x37, 0x32, 0x2D, 
                                    0x61, 0x30, 0x66, 0x66, 0x2D, 0x32, 0x65, 0x62, 0x33, 0x61, 0x33, 0x61, 0x34, 0x32, 0x66, 0x35, 
                                    0x66, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC8, 0x7B, 0x22, 0x49, 0x73, 0x49, 0x6E, 0x69, 0x74, 0x22, 0x3A, 0x74, 
                                    0x72, 0x75, 0x65, 0x2C, 0x22, 0x49, 0x73, 0x41, 0x75, 0x64, 0x69, 0x6F, 0x22, 0x3A, 0x66, 0x61, 
                                    0x6C, 0x73, 0x65, 0x2C, 0x22, 0x54, 0x6F, 0x74, 0x61, 0x6C, 0x53, 0x65, 0x63, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x64, 
                                    0x73, 0x22, 0x3A, 0x30, 0x2E, 0x30, 0x2C, 0x22, 0x46, 0x72, 0x61, 0x6D, 0x65, 0x54, 0x69, 0x6D, 
                                    0x65, 0x22, 0x3A, 0x22, 0x32, 0x30, 0x32, 0x33, 0x2D, 0x30, 0x32, 0x2D, 0x32, 0x35, 0x54, 0x31, 
                                    0x36, 0x3A, 0x35, 0x30, 0x3A, 0x32, 0x37, 0x2E, 0x32, 0x36, 0x31, 0x5A, 0x22, 0x2C, 0x22, 0x53, 
                                    0x65, 0x71, 0x75, 0x65, 0x6E, 0x63, 0x65, 0x49, 0x64, 0x22, 0x3A, 0x31, 0x2C, 0x22, 0x42, 0x61, 
                                    0x73, 0x65, 0x44, 0x65, 0x63, 0x6F, 0x64, 0x65, 0x54, 0x69, 0x6D, 0x65, 0x22, 0x3A, 0x30, 0x2C, 
                                    0x22, 0x4D, 0x65, 0x64, 0x69, 0x61, 0x54, 0x69, 0x6D, 0x65, 0x22, 0x3A, 0x30, 0x2C, 0x22, 0x49, 
                                    0x73, 0x46, 0x72, 0x61, 0x6D, 0x65, 0x48, 0x69, 0x64, 0x64, 0x65, 0x6E, 0x22, 0x3A, 0x66, 0x61,
                                    0x6C, 0x73, 0x65, 0x2C, 0x22, 0x49, 0x73, 0x4B, 0x65, 0x79, 0x46, 0x72, 0x61, 0x6D, 0x65, 0x22, 
                                    0x3A, 0x66, 0x61, 0x6C, 0x73, 0x65, 0x2C, 0x22, 0x49, 0x64, 0x22, 0x3A, 0x30, 0x2C, 0x22, 0x47,
                                    0x65, 0x6E, 0x65, 0x72, 0x61, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x22, 0x3A, 0x31, 0x7D, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02,
                                    0xC4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1C, 0x66, 0x74, 0x79, 0x70, 0x64, 0x61, 0x73, 0x68, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                                    0x00, 0x69, 0x73, 0x6F, 0x6D, 0x64, 0x61, 0x73, 0x68, 0x6D, 0x70, 0x34, 0x31, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 
                                    0xA8, 0x6D, 0x6F, 0x6F, 0x76, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x78, 0x6D, 0x76, 0x68, 0x64, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 
                                    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xE0, 0x1F, 0xEC, 0xD3, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xE0, 0x1F, 0xEC
                                  
                                };

        //# Process the packet to extract MP4 data
        int[] data_MP4 = process_Packet( bytes_Packet ); //# returns a trimmed array
    }
    
    static int[] process_Packet( int[] input ) 
    {
        //# (optional) Confirm function code is running ....
        System.out.println( "## Checking received Packet byte values .... " );
        
        //# NOTE: 
        //# "size_header_Genetec" is the mentioned "skipSize" variable equivalent.
        //# it stores how much bytes length (size) to skip past to reach MP4 data.
        
        int temp_int = 0; //# temp number for counting
        int size_total_packet = input.length; //# using size of "input" packet given to this function
        int size_header_Genetec = 0;
        
        //# first check if this packet's MP4 data needs to be added to another previous packet's data to make a full (uncorrupt) chunk.
        if( need_more_MP4_data == true)
        {
            //## to fix later (if needed)
            //## solution: extract needed remainder and append to an existing array
        }
        
        ///////////////////////////////
        //### Phase 1: Find MP4 attoms
        ///////////////////////////////
        
        //# Account for starting "0x01" byte
        size_header_Genetec = 1;
        
        //# since the size is increased with a "+=" we can re-use
        //# the newly increased "size_header_Genetec" value.
        
        //# get next size (usually String of 4 letters: "H264")
        temp_int = read_int32( input, size_header_Genetec );
        size_header_Genetec += (temp_int + 4);
        
        //# get next size (usually a GUUID of hex values)
        temp_int = read_int32( input, size_header_Genetec );
        size_header_Genetec += (temp_int + 4);
        
        //# get next size (usually an Object of metadata values)
        temp_int = read_int32( input, size_header_Genetec );
        size_header_Genetec += (temp_int + 4);
        
        //# skip next 4 bytes
        size_header_Genetec += 4;
       
        //# Update offset for later use ...
        offset_MP4_data = size_header_Genetec;
        
        //# final check before next steps
        System.out.println( "- MP4 data begins at offset: [" + offset_MP4_data + "] until end of this packet" );
        
        ////////////////////////////////
        //### Phase 2: Handle MP4 atoms
        ////////////////////////////////
        
        //# check atom NAME
        temp_int = read_int32( input, offset_MP4_data + 4 );
        
        if( 
            //# IF atom "name" is one of these (as expected from your packet MP4 structure)...
            ( temp_int == 0x66747970 )    //# is "ftyp"
            || ( temp_int == 0x6D6F6F76 ) //# is "moov"
            || ( temp_int == 0x6D6F6F66 ) //# is "moof"
            || ( temp_int == 0x6D646174 ) //# is "mdat"
            
        )
        {
            //# THEN check all MP4 atoms in this packet for total size of MP4 data
            //# do this by adding together all the atom sizes
            //# note: if size is bigger than packet, then store data for completion with next packet
            
            //# add sizes of MP4 atoms...
            
            temp_int = offset_MP4_data;
                
            while(true)
            {
                size_expected_MP4_data += read_int32( input, temp_int );
                temp_int = ( offset_MP4_data + size_expected_MP4_data );
                
                //# avoid reading past end of packet
                if( size_expected_MP4_data >= ( size_total_packet - offset_MP4_data ) )
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        
        }
        
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //# confirm MP4 data positions are correct (double-check by a hex view of same bytes)...
        System.out.println( ">> MP4 data offset: " + offset_MP4_data );
        System.out.println( ">> MP4 data length is : " + size_expected_MP4_data );
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        
        ///////////////////////////////
        //# Phase 3: Copy the MP4 data
        ///////////////////////////////
        
        int copyStartPos = offset_MP4_data;
        int copyEndPos = (size_total_packet-1);
        
        //# prepare for when getting the next new packet
        
        if( size_expected_MP4_data > ( size_total_packet - offset_MP4_data ) ) { need_more_MP4_data = true; }
        
        if( need_more_MP4_data == false )
        {
            //# reset the count for this new MP4 chunk
            //size_received_MP4_data = 0;
            //size_expected_MP4_data = 0;
        }
        
        //# slice the Array to keep only the MP4 data parts
        return ( Arrays.copyOfRange( input , copyStartPos, copyEndPos) );
        
    }
    
    //# function expects:    
    //# "input" = array to search, 
    //# "pos" = start position of reading a 4-byte sequence 
    static int read_int32( int[] input, int pos ) 
    {
        
        //# integer to hold combined 4-byte values as one result/number
        int temp_int = 0;
        
        //# join the four byte values into "temp_int"
        temp_int = ( input[ pos+0 ] << 24 );
        temp_int |= ( input[ pos+1 ] << 16 );
        temp_int |= ( input[ pos+2 ] << 8 );
        temp_int |= ( input[ pos+3 ] << 0 );

        return ( temp_int ); 
        
    }
        
}
```

Options for stream playback:

**(a)** If your player expects MP4 data:

- Your data is already playable in most video players
- Send all data of each packet, after skipping past the first 49 bytes and also the `{ ... }` Object bytes.

**(b)** If your player expects raw H.264 data (*ie:* It does not play the MP4 data, only H.264 data):

- Then you will have to extract each H.264 video frame from inside the MP4 data.
- Your H.264 data is in **AVCC** format (***.mp4***), which means each frame comes with a "size in bytes" value.
- Most players will expect raw H.264 to be in **AnnexB** format (***.h264***).
   Replace all four bytes of frame's size with this four byte sequence `00 00 00 01`.
  (correctly: Use `00 00 00 01` for SPS, PPS and Keyframes, then `00 00 01` for  other frames *eg:* P-frames).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, with code example.. i will accept this

Comment: Thanks. **(1)** Please re-test the code. I noticed a small mistake (which you might have fixed anyway) about the **copyEndPos**. It should have been the last byte position of packet bytes but I had temporarily put the copy size (instead of a copy position). Fixed now. **(2)** What is your front-end (a web page)? Also are you able to get a keyframe? the goal is to get a video frame displaying...

Comment: Ok, thanks for clariifcation.my frontend is angular. My goal is to get the video playing at the frontend

Comment: I don't use Angular. I ask because I need to know what will decode the video (what player API or component) to check if that thing can play MP4 data as you have from Genetec. Anyways from research I see it uses HTML5 elements like `<img>` etc, so... **(1)** Are you actually using a `<video>` tag to play videos in your Angular app? **(2)** Does Genetec have a config/settings to set how often a keyframe is transmitted (_eg:_ test by setting a keyframe every 1 second) **(3)** Your H.264 stream has a type setting of **avc3**. Can you change that to **avc1** anywhere in the settings?

Comment: The issue with AVC3 is that it means the SPS and PPS are sent with a keyframe. The PPS (Picture Parameter Settings) and the SPS (Sequence Parameter Settings) are needed to know the width/height and other important displaying and decoding details. AVC1 puts these SPS/PPS in the MOOV (so it's in first packet), AVC3 means you will need a keyframe in one of your packets otherwise no picture can be displayed.

Comment: I have made the required modification, to remove the extra header added by the genetic and the custom object metadata by their size, still the packets sent to frontend are not getting played. I tried dumping the packets to a file and ran in VLC, it shows corrupted NAL packets. I have seen that my keyframe comes in each second packet from the socket. please have a look at my modified packet dump

Comment: 1 packet => https://pastebin.com/embed_js/b9HnhxGP

Comment: 2nd packet (last part ommitted) => https://pastebin.com/embed_js/gdHMeLX0

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for updating. Your newly edited packets are in a playable structure now. **(1)** From each packet: If you simply **remove the first four bytes** then the rest is a correct chunk. Test that edit in VLC. To fix in your own code for removing the custom Object metadata, it should simply **add a +4** to the final **Size** of total bytes to remove. PS: The example Java code was already doing this fix (_see:_ line  `//# skip next 4 bytes`). **(2)** I will update later today (after testing) with a final solution to display frames in Angular.

Comment: PS: (I will delete this comment soon, **do not reply this**, just sharing a personal thought): Basically your code is now doing what `ffmpeg -i genetec.mp4 -c copy normal.mp4` would have achieved. However that command won't work in FFmpeg, because it doesn't understand the Genetec header and will assume the input MP4 is corrupt. That means your code is doing what FFmpeg cannot do. My point is: It's not impossible to create your own solutions. Also this byte-slice process has given you same skills to (a) Extract images from MP3, (b) Repair corrupt MP4 (no battery during recording), (c) Trim MP4

Comment: I will update you after removing the first 4 bytes from each packet.

Comment: I've tested things in Chrome browser and yes your file (after the first 4-byte removal editing) should play in a HTML5 `<video>` tag. I suspect VLC doesn't like the H.264 part to be in AVC3 format. Angular uses the `<video>` tag, so it should work there too.

Comment: Great , Things started working after removing the first 4 bytes from my last shown packets in hex dump. Can you please tell me what those 4 bytes meant and why is their removal made everything work ?

Answer (score 4):

Your hex dump looks like a partial fragmented MP4 prefixed with some JSON.
Typically H.264 uses inter frame compression.
So not every frame is a full frame but just the differences between two frames.
Therefore you can't decode H.264 at arbitrary points.
You need to look for an IDR (instant decoder refresh) frame in your stream.
IDR frames may only be transmitted every 10-100 frames.
Now I am looking at your 'mdat' hex dump

00 00 3E E8 6D 64 61 74 00 00 3E DC 41

00 00 3E E8 : size of 'mdat'

6D 64 61 74 : 'mdat'

00 00 3E DC : size of the NAL unit (part of the H.264) stream

41 : indicates NAL unit type of '1' (lower 4 bits indicate NAL unit type)

NAL unit of type '1' is a coded slice of a non-IDR picture.

So your 'mdat' does not contain an IDR (or key) frame therefore it is not decodable.

If you look at your JSON - you'll get another datapoint indicating the lack of a keyframe ("IsKeyFrame":false).

```
{
"IsInit":false,
"IsAudio":false,
"TotalSeconds":0.06,
"FrameTime":"2023-02-23T04:21:53.531Z",
"SequenceId":1,
"BaseDecodeTime":26587,
"MediaTime":26587,
"IsFrameHidden":false,
"IsKeyFrame":false,
"Id":445,"Generation":1
}
```

So you could modify your code and start decoding once you receive and IDR or key frame.
But there is potentially another issue.
You may need certain metadata to prime the H.264 decoder that you typically find in 'moov' (and not 'moof') part of the fragmented mp4.

The stream metadata is called Sequence Parameter Set (SPS) and Picture Parameter Set (PPS).
It is legal to omit SPS and PPS in 'mdat' since it is usually factored out into the 'moov'.

Handing just the 'mdat' to a H.264 decoder may not work if SPS/PPS is missing.

In any case - if your IDR frames are prefixed with SPS/PPS - you still have to remove the size field(s) from the 'mdat' and replace them with start codes (00 00 00 01)

Essentially you have to convert the mp4-style H.264 stream from 'mdat' into a 'AnnexB'-style before feeding it into a decoder:

Your 'mdat':

```
'mdat' = <size> data[0] | <size> data[1] | ... | <size> data[n] |
```

Replace the size with a start code and break the multiple Access Units into individual Access Units.

Required decoder input:

```
00 00 00 01 data[0]
00 00 00 01 data[1]
...
00 00 00 01 data[n]
```

If your 'mdat' does not contain SPS/PPS then your best bet is to wait or request the 'moov' or init part of the fragmented mp4 and hand the complete fragmented mp4 to ffmpeg.

I am guessing that the 'moov' or init part of the fragmented MP4 will be prefixed with the JSON member ("IsInit":true).

A previous answer [Decoding H264 Stream Always Returns MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73036143/decoding-h264-stream-always-returns-mf-e-transform-need-more-input/73085083#73085083)

links a self contained example parsing 'mdat' and handing it to Media Foundation for decoding.