# First/single frame encoded with ffmpeg/libavcodec library cannot be immediately decoded

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, h.264, libavcodec, x264

I'm using libavcodec library and h264 codec to prepare the video stream on one end, transmit the encoded frames to the other PC and there decode it.

What I noticed after receiving very first packet (first encoded video frame) and feeding decoder with it, it is not possible to decode that frame. Only when I receive another frame the first one can be decoded but 'current' one not. So in the end I have constantly one frame delay on the decoder side.

I was trying different `preset`s (focusing rather on `'ultrafast'`), also `'zerolatency'` `tune`, also whole variety of `bit_rate` values of `AVCodecContext`.

I also tried to flush (with nullptr packet) after injecting first frame data, just to check if it is maybe because of some internal buffers optimization - the frame still not decoded.
Experimenting with other codecs (like mpeg4) gives even worse 'dalay' in number of frames to the point when when first frames can become decodable.

Is it normal, unavoidable because of some internal mechanisms? Otherwise how I can achieve real zero latency.

Supplementary setup information:

- `max_b_frames` set to 0 (higher value gives even more delay)
- `pix_fmt` set to `AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P`

*edit:*

Answering some comment question:

> (1) What is the decoder (or playback system)?

Custom decoder written using libavcodec, the decoded frames are later displayed on screen by OpenGL.

- initialization:

```
parser_ = av_parser_init(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
codec_ = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
context_ = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec_);
context_->width = 1024;
context_->height = 768;
context_->thread_count = 1;
if ((codec_->capabilities & AV_CODEC_CAP_TRUNCATED) == 0)
{
  context_->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_TRUNCATED;
}
if (avcodec_open2(context_, codec_, nullptr) < 0)
{
  throw std::runtime_error{"avcodec_open2 failed"};
}
avcodec_flush_buffers(context_);
```

- then player periodically calls of the method of decoder that suppose to check if the another frame can be retrieved and displayed:

```
auto result = avcodec_receive_frame(context_, frame_);
if (!buffer_.empty())
{  // upload another packet for decoding
  int used;
  if (upload_package(buffer_.data(), buffer_.size(), &used))
  {
    buffer_.erase(buffer_.begin(), buffer_.begin() + used);
  }
}
if (result == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || result == AVERROR_EOF || result < 0)
{
  return false;
}
yuv_to_rgb();
return true;
```

boolean return value informs if the decoding succeeded, and every time the buffer where the incomming packets are stored is checked and uploaded to libavcodec decoder

- and that is how the method that uploads the buffer looks like:

```
bool upload_package(const void* data, const std::size_t size, int* used)
{
  auto result = av_parser_parse2(parser_, context_, &packet_->data, &packet_->size, reinterpret_cast<const std::uint8_t*>(data), size, AV_NOPTS_VALUE, AV_NOPTS_VALUE, 0);
  if (result < 0)
  {
    return false;
  }
  *used = result;
  if (packet_->size != 0)
  {
    result = avcodec_send_packet(context_, packet_);
    if (result < 0)
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

> (2) If possible, save each one as a `.bin` file and then share the links with us for testing.

I will try to figure out something...

> (3) Show example C++ code of your encoder settings for H264...

- initialization:

```
codec_ = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
context_ = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec_);

context_->bit_rate = 1048576; // 1xMbit;
context_->width = 1024;
context_->height = 768;
context_->time_base = {1, 30}; // 30 fps
context_->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
context_->thread_count = 1;

av_opt_set(context_->priv_data, "preset", "ultrafast", 0);
av_opt_set(context_->priv_data, "tune", "zerolatency", 0);
avcodec_open2(context_, codec_, nullptr);

frame_->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
frame_->width = 1024;
frame_->height = 768;
av_image_alloc(frame_->data, frame_->linesize, 1024, 768, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, 32);
```

- frame encoding:

```
rgb_to_yuv();
frame_->pts = frame_num_++;
auto result = avcodec_send_frame(context_, frame_);
while (result >= 0)
{
  result = avcodec_receive_packet(context_, packet_);
  if (result == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || result == AVERROR_EOF)
  {
    return;
  }
  else if (result < 0)
  {
    throw std::runtime_error{"avcodec_receive_packet failed"};
  }
  // here the packet is send to the decoder, the whole packet is stored on the mentioned before buffer_ and uploaded with avcodec_send_packet
  // I can also add that the whole buffer/packet us uploaded at once
  stream_video_data(packet_->data, packet_->size); 
}
av_packet_unref(packet_);
}
```

*edit2:*

I think I figured out the issue that I had.

For every incoming data packet (encoded frame) I was calling first `av_parser_parse2`, and then I was sending the data through `avcodec_send_packet`.
And I was not recalling that procedure having empty `buffer_`, so for the first frame data the `av_parser_parse2` was never called after uploading it through `avcodec_send_packet`, for the second frame it was called and the first frame was parsed, so it could be properly decoded, but for that (second) frame the parse2 was also not called, and so on ...

So the issue in my case was wrong sequence of `av_parser_parse2` and `avcodec_send_packet` to handle the encoded data.

Comment: There is not enough info to start helping you. **(1)** What is the decoder (or playback system)? **(2)** How can we check your first 2 packets? If possible, save each one as a `.bin` file and then share the links with us for testing. **(3)** Show example C++ code of your encoder settings for H264. It's possible you are getting one complete frame being divided such that it needs to be sent within two packets but nobody knows what you did (your settings) to make it output like that...

Comment: @VC.One thanks for comment, I uploaded some code snippets for the completion, but I think I found the issue, my `upload_package` was not well organised and the parsing procedure was not called at proper moment - I will edit to explain that.

Comment: @MarekKijo - put yourself into the shoes of the dev who wants to reproduce.
1.  none of your code snippet can be compiled - Give a complete minimal compliable example
2. include the sample media/stream as file

Take a look at the question and my answer of 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73036143/decoding-h264-stream-always-returns-mf-e-transform-need-more-input

The question is technically not related to your issue but it contains a minimal example that compiles with all the data. So you can get a good idea what I expect.